# Is user vimfiles/after/ftplugin supposed to be after system/indent?

Tags: vimrc

Should user `vimfiles/after/ftplugin` scripts loaded after any system script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with a blank `vimrc`:

```
" Hello, world!
```

Vim doesn't do any filetype-specific stuff by default: no ftplugins, no syntax highlighting, nothing.

We can tell Vim to start doing filetype-specific stuff, namely syntax highlighting, by adding the following line (or `syntax enable`, but that's a debate for another day):

```
syntax on
```

which tells Vim to try sourcing syntax scripts in the following order:

```
~/.vim/syntax/javascript.vim
$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/javascript.vim
~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim
```

when you edit a `*.js` file.

From there, you can enable filetype plugins by adding the following line:

```
filetype plugin on
```

which tells Vim to try sourcing filetype plugins in the following order:

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/javascript.vim
$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/javascript.vim
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim
```

Now, as mentioned by @Matt, in the comments, order matters. If you have this:

```
syntax on
filetype plugin on
```

then Vim tries to source the syntax scripts before the filetype plugins:

```
~/.vim/syntax/javascript.vim
$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/javascript.vim
~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim
~/.vim/ftplugin/javascript.vim
$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/javascript.vim
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim
```

but, if you have this:

```
filetype plugin on
syntax on
```

then the filetype plugins are tried before the syntax scripts:

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/javascript.vim
$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/javascript.vim
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim
~/.vim/syntax/javascript.vim
$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/javascript.vim
~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim
```

which I think is extremely silly.

Now, there are two ways to enable indent scripts. One is to add a line like this:

```
filetype indent on
```

and the other is to combine it with an existing `filetype plugin on` line:

```
filetype plugin indent on
filetype indent plugin on
```

Again, order matters. If you have this:

```
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

then the filetype plugins are tried before the indent scripts. But, if you have this:

```
filetype indent on
filetype plugin on
```

then the indent scripts are tried before the filetype plugins.

Funnily enough, the order of `indent` and `plugin` in:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

has no effect on the order in which the scripts are sourced: it is always filetype plugins first and indent scripts second.

In my own config, I have the following:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

which tells Vim to source the filetype plugins first, then the indent scripts, and then the syntax scripts. YMMV.

So… the only order that is more or less guaranteed (assuming a relatively normal setup) is the one *within* a "family" of scripts:

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/javascript.vim
$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/javascript.vim
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim
```

You can definitely expect any runtime script to be sourced after `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`, so there is no reason to expect that `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` will be sourced after everything else.

If you are looking for a way to do some setup *after everything else has been set up*, then `after/ftplugin/` is not it.

Comment: @Matt, I tried to make my answer more comprehensive.